# Picking up CSV fields by name using awk

Tags: csv, awk, gawk

Suppose I have a CSV file with headers of the following form:

```
Field1,Field2
3,262000
4,449000
5,650000
6,853000
7,1061000
8,1263000
9,1473000
10,1683000
11,1893000
```

**I would like to write an awk script which will take a comma-separated list of field names `target`, split it into an array, and then only pick out those columns with the names I specify.**

This is what I have tried so far, and I have verified that the `head` array contains the desired headers, and the `targets` array contains the desired targets passed in by the given command line.

```
BEGIN{
    FS=","
    split(target, targets, ",")

}

NR==1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) head[i] = $i
}

NR !=1{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (head[i] in targets){
            print $i
        }
    }
}
```

When I invoke this script with the command

> awk -v target=Field1 -f GetCol.awk Debug.csv

I get nothing printed out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out and am posting the answer in case others run into the same problem.

It has to do with the `in` keyword I am using for testing array membership. 
This keyword only tests whether the operand on the left is one of the **indices** in the array on the right, rather than on of the values. 
The fix is to create a reverse-lookup array, as follows.

```
BEGIN{
    OFS=FS=","
    split(target, t_targets, ",")
    for (i in t_targets)
        targets[t_targets[i]] = i
}
```

Comment: +1 for figuring it out yourself! I Added a full script to the job, you may find some of it helpful.

Answer (score 6):

My two cents:

```
BEGIN{
    OFS=FS=","
    split(target,fields,FS)            # We just set FS don't hard the comma here
    for (i in fields)                  # Distinct var name to aviod headaches
        field_idx[fields[i]] = i       # Reverse lookup 
}
NR==1 {                                # Process header
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # For each field header
        head[i] = $i                   # Add to hash for comparision with target
    next                               # Skip to next line
}
{                                      # Don't need invert condition (used next)
    sep=""                             # Set for leading separator
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # For each field
        if (head[i] in field_idx) {    # Test for current field is a target field
            printf "%s%s",sep,$i       # Print the column if matched 
            sep=OFS                    # Set separator to OFS                  
    }
    printf "\n"                        # Print newline character
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An extension of @sudo_O's solution (thank you) that

1. outputs fields from standard input based on the command line arguments,
2. outputs the fields in the order requested (possibly multiple times),
3. outputs a placeholder when a field was requested but not found, and
4. warns on standard error about duplicate field names in the header.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Process standard input outputting named columns provided as arguments.
#
# For example, given foo.dat containing
#     a b c c
#     1a 1b 1c 1C
#     2a 2b 2c 2C
#     3a 3b 3c 3C
# Running
#   cat foo.dat | ./namedcols c b a a d
# will output
#   1c 1b 1a 1a d
#   2c 2b 2a 2a d
#   3c 3b 3a 3a d
# and will warn on standard error that it
#   Ignored duplicate 'c' in column 4
# Notice that the requested but missing column d contains "d".
#
# Using awk's -F feature it is possible to parse comma-separated data:
#   cat foo.csv | ./namedcols -F, c b a a d
BEGIN {
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; ++i)
        desired[i] = ARGV[i]
    delete ARGV
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i in names)
            printf "Ignored duplicate '%s' in column %d\n", $i, i | "cat 1>&2"
        else
            names[$i] = i
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; ++i)
        printf "%s%s",                                          \
               (i==1 ? "" : OFS),                               \
               ((ndx = names[name = desired[i]])>0 ? $ndx: name)
    printf RS
}
```